# Contexts and callbacks from asynchronous tasks

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

I've been experiencing this problem on some devices, especially Samsung.

I have an activity that has 7 `fragments`. In most of them, I start an `async` task for getting some data. I handle the exceptions by creating a handler in o`nCreateView()`.

```
 handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.connection_timed_out), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

When making the `API` call, in `catch` blocks, if exceptions occur, I cancel the `async` task and in the `onCancelled()` callback, I notify the handler.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<UserProfile>>() {
            @Override
            protected ArrayList<UserProfile> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
          return new APIService().GetUserProfiles(EnloopApplication.getCurrent().getAuthenticationToken(), thisUserProfile.getEnloop_friends());
            } catch (WampNetworkException e) {
                cancel(true);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (WampApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                cancel(true);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
```

On most devices, it works, but on `Samsung` devices sometimes I get `null pointer exception` since `getActivity()` returns nothing, as if the `activity` was destroyed and never got created again. Problem is the activity is not destroyed in code, since only thing that is happening is switching between `fragments` in same `activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getActivity()` returning `null` is a perfectly valid scenario which you should expect as well.

This happens because by creating anonymous `Handler` in your `onCreateView` you're referencing `Fragment` which was already detached from `Activity` (therefore `getActivity()` returns `null`). Same goes for your `AsyncTask` - if you're creating it as an anonymous class inside `Fragment` then it also references same detached `Fragment`.

I would suggest you to revise your architecture. How? I believe, is that your UI components should not perform asynchronous operations by themselves. Instead, you should use any sort of publish/subscribe mechanism out there (there are solutions which are using `LoaderManager`, `HandlerThread`, RxJava, RoboSpice and other 3rd party libraries).

Comment: Thank you :) Was thinking about using Retrofit, since it contains Rxjava

Comment: @Alex as you might imagine, there are lots of way to avoid it with they own advantages and disadvantages. Personally, I prefer RxJava + MVP pattern. You can (better) Google it, there are lots of articles and examples already.

Comment: Will do some reading about those :) Thank you for the helpful insight